# How to process 1.2 million messages per second using apache samza?

Tags: apache-samza

Now i made basic setup of samza .
   After that i process 1,00,000 json records which is from kafka broker topic
   Each records in size of 100 bytes
   But per second i can only process 11000 records.
   How to increase processing speed?

Answer (score 0):

If you need more broker you can increase number partition :

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zoo:port/chroot --alter --topic TOPIC_NAME_CHANGE_ME --partitions 10
```

So nb partition == nb worker

For more information : [Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-5.AddPartitionTool)